# XAMPP dont works correctly in my ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, php, phpmyadmin, xampp

my xammp servers dont works correctly.. I cannt make it running anyway.[XAMPP Manage Servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEGjs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have any other services utilising the port (80) that the XAMPP Apache server uses. There might even be another Apache server running on your server (run "sudo apt-get remove apache2" to remove it).

If you can't find anything that is using that port, then try changing the port of the server from 80 to something like 8080 by going to "Configure" then restarting the services in that XAMPP control panel.